# How to resize c# marker images?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I am trying to make a neat little bar graph with unique markers on the columns. 
I used a 20x20px png image for this purpose and set it with

```
chart1.Series[0].Points[chart1.Series[0].Points.Count - 1].MarkerImage = imageIWanToUse;
```

but the marker is huge, tried to use

```
chart1.Series[0].Points[chart1.Series[0].Points.Count - 1].MarkerSize = 1;
```

but with no luck, i get this on all of the columns, where can i fix this?

[image of a column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQ1CS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the image you use has the proper `dpi` setting, so that it fits with your screen's dp, which probably is around 75-96 dpi.

If it looks too large than the `dpi` of the image is too small..

You can change it in code like this:

```
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) Bitmap.FromFile("D:\\stop32.png");
bmp.SetResolution(50, 50);
bmp.Save("D:\\stop32_50dpi.png");
bmp.SetResolution(250, 250);
bmp.Save("D:\\stop32_250dpi.png");

Series S0 = chart1.Series[0];

S0.Points[chart1.Series[0].Points.Count - 3].MarkerImage = "D:\\stop32.png";
S0.Points[chart1.Series[0].Points.Count - 2].MarkerImage = "D:\\stop32_50.png";
S0.Points[chart1.Series[0].Points.Count - 1].MarkerImage = "D:\\stop32_250.png";
```

Here are the resulting markers:

[image]

The original resolution was 96dpi. (Left marker.)

You will have to watch out for varying screen `dpi` and use either different images or create the right one dynamically. You can get the current screen `dpi` e.g. by testing the current `Graphics` object in a `Paint` event: `Console.WriteLine(e.Graphics.DpiX + " dpi x");` For my screen this resulted in 120 dpi..

Comment: i used a 20x20px image for the marker, but it shows up like a 50x50px one, the 20x20px image (according to inkscape) is 35.29dpi. [link](http://i.imgur.com/mdi90MY.png)

Comment: Exactly. The dpi of your monitor probably is around 75-120 dpi. So it looks too large, you like I wrote.. Try saving it with 75 or 96 dpi! - You will have to watch out for varying screen dpi and use either different images or create the right one dynamically. You can get the current  screen dpi e.g. by testing the current Graphics object in a `Paint` event: `Console.WriteLine(e.Graphics.DpiX + " dpi x");` For my screen this resulted in 120 dpi..

Comment: Still getting the same size [marker](http://i.imgur.com/P3NDeEV.png) the first image is 50dpi, second is 250dpi, and the third is the original image 35,29dpi. But, it was the dpi that made the image too big, tried to search further i found [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BeAwareOfDPIWithImagePNGsInWPFImagesScaleWeirdOrAreBlurry.aspx) thank you for your help.